# What is this "Screen Shot" app using so much battery?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, power-management

The battery on my MacBook Pro drains very quickly compared to what other people report.

When I'm running Slack, lots of Chrome tabs, and Docker for Mac and everything, that's to be expected.  However, when I close everything I'm still seeing drain and the energy app say that a major consumer is "Screen Shot" but when I click on it, it takes me to Activity Monitor - which does not show anything called "Screen Shot".

Take a look:

[image]

I have a MacBook Pro 2017 running 10.14

Does anyone happen to know what this is and what I can do to quit the app?

Comment: That screen is just a summary and provides no context. To see what's the actual energy impact is, you need to use [Activity Monitor](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201464#energy).  It's also advisable to indicate which MacBook Pro you have and which version of macOS you're running.

Comment: Does it go away (permanently) if you reboot your machine? That might be the simplest solution, I'm guessing the screen shot utility is just hanging for some reason.

Comment: Let me also just take this opportunity to hate on Slack's performance. Instant messaging apps should not use significant energy. It's typical of Slack (ie not a machine specific issue), but that's awful.

Comment: @allan 15" macbook pro 2017 running 10.14

Comment: @Wowfunhappy Slack is built on electron, which uses Chromium.  The problem is out of Slack's hands unless they abandon Chromium.

Comment: @JohnRuiz Not all Electron apps perform as poorly as Slack—Visual Studio Code for instance is relatively lightweight. But, also, they're not a tiny startup any longer, and they *should* be building native apps.